# Run-time error 1004 when adding data validation. How do I avoid the error?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following procedure to add data validation to a cell:

```
Sub SetDataValidationList(r As Range, s As String)
    Dim dv As Validation
    Set dv = r.Validation

    With dv
        .Delete
        If s <> "" Then
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=s
        Else
            'The backup string could be a parameter
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="None available"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

It worked while I was developing the Excel file for a few days, but now for some reason the row `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=s` throws run-time error 1004. What might be the reason? How can I avoid the error?

`s` is `"1.1,PM,PA,OE,MOA1,MOA2,MOA3,MOA4"`

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. The reason is that the sheet was protected.